# Bitwise operations on memory addresses

Tags: arithmetic

I have to solve a question saying

> The value of ab if ab & 0x3f equals 0x27.

Consider a, b as hex digits. Then `b&f` means `b&1111` - the book explains that `b&1111` should yield `0111` i.e. `7` => a should be 7.
The book says `a&0011`should yield `a = 2` but doesn't provide an explanation.

Please help me understand why `a&0011 = 2` implies `a = 2`.

Comment: This is a space for research-level questions, not homework questions - please ask this on StackOverflow instead. Also, please clarify the question - I'm having a really hard time understanding what's being asked and what you tried. Is "ab" a single variable or a composite of a and b? Is the goal to find the value of ab, of a and b, or something else? What's M and N? What book are you talking about? etc. (please don't reply to me here - repost the question instead. I'm voting to close the question here.)

Comment: @jkff and whoever upvoted that comment. Your comment is so wrong I barely know where to begin. CS Stack Exchange is *not* for research-level questions only. And this question isn't a programming question so it's not on-topic at [SO]. The question seems clear enough to me: you ask what M and N are but they're near-enough explicitly stated to be the two hex digits of "ab", which seems to be a single value. And please, *never* advise somebody to repost a question: questions should be *edited* to improve them and *migrated* if they're in the wrong place.

Comment: this Stackexchange is made worse by now

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ok, sorry, apparently I was mistaken about the way homework questions should be dealt with - I think I saw long-timers of this SE deal with them in the same way previously, so I just did the thing I thought was right.

Comment: @jkff OK -- thanks for trying to help. The next time will be better, I'm sure. :-)

Comment: I edited the question and tags according to my improved understanding.

Comment: They will not aid you with basic stuff. They're too advanced for it.

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, you have to solve two equations, the first one is $N \& 1111_b = 0111_b$ the other $M \& 0011_b = 0010_b$.

To solve these equations notice that every bit in these equations acts independently of the other bits. For example let $N1,N2,N3,N4$ the bits of $N$, i.e.,

```
 N1 N2 N3 N4    
+ 1  1  1  1
------------
  0  1  1  1
```

Since $N4 \& 1 = 1$ the value of $N4$ has to be $1$. Now continue with the other bits. If you have problems inverting the and look at the truth table. Note that the inversion is not always unique: If you ask for $0 \& X = 0$ then $X$ can be either $1$ or $0$.